# Как избавиться от xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"

Tags: java, xml, spring, null

`<tag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>`  жлаемый вид-> `<tag/>`
Как этого достичь?

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Name implements Serializable{

@XmlElement(nillable = true)
    private String tag;

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag= tag;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ очевиден. Убери `nillable = true`. Однако, в таком случае, ты получишь отсутствие тэга `<tag>` при значении `null`. Чтобы всегда иметь тэг `<tag>`, необходимо в значение устанавливать пустую строку.

Comment: <tag></tag> тоже не подходит. Нужен пустой тег, а не тег с пустой строкой

Comment: @vlad_nightsky это одно и то же.